# Server:run stuck in other project

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I'm having the following problem:

I use the command `app / console server: run` in a project folder. I then stop the process using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and when I go to another project folder and start the server, my page is still loading the old design.

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Many things can happen, for instance:

* are you sure you are seeing the server you just started.
* caching of the page by the browser.
* does it have the same design in the other project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running this and this resolved for a while...

chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php5
chmod -R 777 /tmp
php app/console cache:clear
chmod -R 777 /tmp
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
php app/console assetic:dump